# Register Android service in source code instead in Android Manifest

Tags: android, service, manifest

Does anyone know that is it possible to register (add) declaration of service in source code instead in AndroidManifest.xml if yes... how?

Thanks for any suggestions or help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible. You have to have your `Service` registered in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#Declaring):

> Like activities (and other components), you must declare all services in your application's manifest file.

So you will allways have to list your `Service` in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

`AndroidManifest.xml` is *part* of your source code. This is the place where Android expects to find your services and activities declared, and there's no way around it.

Comment: Yep. But it'll be really nice when I'm creating api for another developers and I'll be able to add this myself in java code instead others have to worry about it.

Comment: It would also be dangerous, and not very clean I think

Comment: Only one reason for that is when you are using my api than you have to always remeber that you have to set all parameters in manifest. Why u think that can be dangerous?

Comment: I actually agree that it's dangerous. As you can add some services in newer versions of APIs. It is a bit inconvenient, that's true. But I'd rather explicitly declare the service than struggle through docs to find out what services framework might start.

Answer (score 0):

The manifest presents essential information about the application to the Android system, information the system must have before it can run any of the application's code.

So it is mandatory to declare all your components (with their intent filters i.e Category , Action , Data) in your manifest file.